# SQLite and multiple insert clean

Tags: sqlite

I would like to populate a freshly created Table in a SQLite DB.

In this table, some keys are references to other tables and I'd like not to hard-code these references
-> I'm currently using a "mapping" table in order to fetch ids using names (~ constants emulation)

The problem is: this solution works but is *very* verbose

Minimal working example: (storing dictionary words, using foreign keys to a category table)

```
-- Tables creation

CREATE TABLE categories(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE words(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  id_category INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_category) REFERENCES categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE CONSTANTS(
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  value INTEGER NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO categories(name) VALUES("noun");
INSERT INTO CONSTANTS(name, value) VALUES("category_noun", last_insert_rowid());

INSERT INTO categories(name) VALUES("abreviation");
INSERT INTO CONSTANTS(name, value) VALUES("category_abreviation", last_insert_rowid());


INSERT INTO categories(name) VALUES("character");
INSERT INTO CONSTANTS(name, value) VALUES("category_character", last_insert_rowid());
```

And now, the core of the problem: too much verbose.
In this example is only one foreign key, a few insert to illustrate the problem

```
INSERT INTO words(id_category, name) VALUES
   ((SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_noun"),
    "hello"),

   ((SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_abreviation"),
    "SO"),

   ((SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_abreviation"),
    "user"),

   ((SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_character"),
    "!")
;
```

I would like to have something looking like this pseudo-sqlite code:

```
-- same table creations as before

INSERT INTO words(id_category, name) VALUES
   -- Fetch constants once
    CAT_NOUM  = SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_noum"),
    CAT_ABREV = SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_abreviation"),
    CAT_CHAR = SELECT value FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = "category_abreviation")
   )

   -- Fill the table, using constants
   (CAT_NOUM, "Hello"),
   (CAT_ABREV, "SO"),
   (CAT_NOUM, "user"),
   (CAT_CHAR, "SO"),
   ...
;
```

I'm wondering if

- There is already a SQLite solution to this problem
- I should use something like `sed` to replace a hard-coded string like __SED__CAT_NOUM with its `grep`ed value in the SQLite script
- Doing this stuff programmatically would be the right way

Comment: What is `id_language` and `name`? I don't see them in the definition of `words`.

Comment: @forpas Sorry, you're right I fixed the example. I just tested it; copy-pasting + `select * from words` is now ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `INSERT...SELECT` with `UNION ALL` instead of `INSERT...VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO words(id_category, name) 
SELECT value, 'hello' FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = 'category_noun' UNION ALL
SELECT value, 'SO' FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = 'category_abreviation' UNION ALL
SELECT value, 'user' FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = 'category_abreviation' UNION ALL
SELECT value, '!' FROM CONSTANTS WHERE name = 'category_character';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mERhzPaC1D55PFDmG88xuQ/0).

Or use [`Row Values`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) to join to `CONSTANTS`:

```
INSERT INTO words(id_category, name) 
SELECT c.value, t.column2
FROM CONSTANTS C INNER JOIN (
  VALUES ('category_noun', 'hello'),
         ('category_abreviation', 'SO'),  
         ('category_abreviation', 'user'),
         ('category_character', '!')  
) t ON t.column1 = c.name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mERhzPaC1D55PFDmG88xuQ/2).

Results:

```
SELECT * FROM words;

| id  | id_category | name  |
| --- | ----------- | ----- |
| 1   | 1           | hello |
| 2   | 2           | SO    |
| 3   | 2           | user  |
| 4   | 3           | !     |
```